# copy floating point numbers from a dynamic array to another dynamic array in c

Tags: c

Initially an array is allocated to hold five temperatures. The user is now prompted for a new temperature and enters a value of -100.0 on completion to terminate the loop. If the user fills the array, the program should use malloc() to dynamically allocate a new array twice its size and copy the old values into the new array. Release the old array and continue reading the new array. The loop that reads the value is a while loop that terminates when reading stops the value -100.0. In loop, you need to check to see if you have reached the end of the currently allocated array and have code to perform the new allocation, copy, and recycle.

First, Let me share some ideas. The overall design structure should follow the following steps: (1) create a new array, (2) copy the old data into the new array, and (3) free the old array.

My initial idea was to use memcpy () to copy floating point numbers from the old array into the new one. But after consulting the data, this method is not feasible. So I changed my mind and tried to implement the function with for loop, but the intelligent prompt said THAT I could not use the names of the dynamic array I created in the while loop outside the while loop, and I fell into this problem.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    float *temperature = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    float arr[5] ={11.5,12.4,14.6,21.5,30.9}; // an array is allocated to hold five temperatures.
    printf("Please enter the temperature: \n"); // let the user enter the new temperatures
    int arr_index = 0;
    scanf("%f", &arr[arr_index]);  // get the first number
    while (arr[arr_index] != -100.0) {
     arr_index++;
     if (arr_index >= 5) {
         break;  // reached the limit
     }
     int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
     float *new_temperature = malloc(sizeof(float) * (length * 2));
     memcpy(new_temperature,temperature);
     free(temperature);
     temperature = new_temperature;
     scanf("%f", &arr[arr_index]);  // get the next number
   }
    printf("%.1f\n",temperature);
    free(temperature);
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't have any idea how to implement these features.
Thank you all.

Comment: Why copy into a new one? You could just use `realloc`

Comment: BTW what you have, won't even compile.

Comment: You say _"My initial idea was to use `memcpy()` to copy floating point numbers from the old array into the new one. But after consulting the data, this method is not feasible."_. Why do you think that?  Given the choice of using `malloc()` instead of `realloc()`, what is the problem?  (It would be better to use `realloc()` to avoid your code doing the copying, but given your choice, `memmove()` or `memcpy()` seems reasonable.). Alternatively, what's the problem with copying the data in a loop?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler unfortunately, this problem doesn't allow the use of realloc(), I can only use malloc().

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong with your code.

- ### You **will** , probably, go out of bounds of the `arr` array.

`arr_index++;`, this line will keep on increasing `arr_index` until the user decides to enter `-100.0`.

So you rely on the user **not** to enter more than **5** floats. (*Don't ever do that*)

Instead, check that you don't go out of bounds before asking for new input, you also call `scanf()` twice, which doesn't really add up. You just need to call it once, outside the loop, and once at the end.

```
scanf("%f",&arr[arr_index]); // get the first number
while (arr[arr_index] != -100.0) {
    arr_index++;
    if (arr_index >= 5) break; // reached the limit
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    float *new_temperature = malloc(sizeof(float)*(length*2));
    free(temperature);
    temperature = new_temperature;
    scanf("%f",&arr[arr_index]); // get the next number
}
```

- ### You can't access a variable outside of it's scope

```c
      while (arr[arr_index] != -100.0) {
            scanf("%f",&arr[arr_index]);
            arr_index++;
            int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
         //       vvvv Defined in the while scope ({})
            float *new_temperature = malloc(sizeof(float)*(length*2));
            free(temperature);
            temperature = new_temperature;
            scanf("%f",&arr[arr_index]);
        }
      // Can't access it here
```

If you want to copy the data to that array, you have to do it inside the `while` loop.

- ### Your logic can be simplified

You statically allocate an array of **5** floats that you **never** really make use of. Instead, you overwrite the original values.

What you could do is, have one **dynamically allocated** array, use `realloc()` if you ever need to **expand/shrink**.

*Although, there is nothing stopping you from calling `malloc()` again with double size and then using `memmcpy()` or `memmove()`.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    float *temperature = NULL;
    int arr_index = 0, size = 5;

    temperature = malloc(size * sizeof(float)); // cast is redundant 

    if (temperature == NULL) { // malloc failed
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc: failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Please enter the temperature: \n"); // let the user enter the new temperatures
    if (scanf("%f", &temperature[arr_index]) != 1) {  // check the return value of scanf
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf: failed to convert to float\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (temperature[arr_index] != -100.0f) { // f suffix denotes a floating point number
        arr_index++; // increment index

    if (arr_index >= size) { // need more space - call realloc
        size *= 2; // double the size

        float *new_tmp = realloc(temperature, size * sizeof(float));

        if (new_tmp == NULL) { // realloc failed
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc: failed to allocate memory\n");
            // clean up - good practise overall not really necessary here

            free(temperature);
            exit(1);
        }

        temperature = new_tmp;
    }

    // get a new number
    if (scanf("%f", &temperature[arr_index]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf: failed to convert to float\n");
        exit(1);
    }

 }


    // iterate the array and print each element
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_index; i++) {
         printf("%.1f\n", temperature[i]);
    } 

    free(temperature);

    return 0;
}
```

### Edit:

If you have to use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` you have to call `malloc()` again after doubling the size, then just copy `arr_index * sizeof(float)` **bytes** *(since arr_index denotes the size of the array, to get the actual size in bytes, multiply that with the size of float)*.

You have to `#include <string.h>`

```c
while (temperature[arr_index] !=-100.0f) {  // f suffix denotes a floating point number
    arr_index++;     // increment index

    if (arr_index >= size) {  // need more space - call malloc
      size *= 2;              // double the size

      float *new_tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(float));

      if (new_tmp == NULL) {  // malloc failed
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc: failed to allocate memory\n");
        // clean up - good practise overall not really necessary here

        free(temperature);
        exit(1);
      }
      // memcpy syntax is similar
      // copy arr_index * sizeof(float) bytes from temp to new_tmp
      memmove(new_tmp, temperature, arr_index * sizeof(float));

      free(temperature);
      temperature = new_tmp;
    }

    // get a new number
    if (scanf("%f", &temperature[arr_index]) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "scanf: failed to convert to float\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As for why I didn't use memcpy, it was because the system reported an error.

Comment: I will modify my code and show

Comment: Since this question is examining the ability to allocate arrays, it says please do not use the realloc() function

Comment: In file included from temperatures02.c:3:
/usr/include/string.h:43:14: note: declared here
   43 | extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
      |              ^~~~~~
temperatures02.c:28:14: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
   28 |   printf("%.1f\n", temperature);

Comment: @Cedricxu I have modified my answer.